# How to generate a sequence of string of numbers in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, sequence

How can I generate a sequence of string numbers in a list in python?
For example I want numbers starting from 3000 to 3100 that are stored in a list and are also in string format.

Something like this
['3000', '3001', '3002', ......., '3100']

Comment: `[str(n) for n in range(3000, 3101)]`

Comment: `[*map(str, range(3000, 3100 + 1))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
[str(i) for i in range(3000, 3100+1)]
```

This is faster than using `map()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `range` function, then combine with a `map(str,)`

```
# list of int
values = list(range(3000, 3101))
print(values)  # [3000, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004 ... 3100]

# list of string representation of int
values = list(map(str, range(3000, 3101)))
print(values)  # ['3000', '3001', '3002', '3003',, ... '3100']
```

Comment: @Vignesh Can you show expected result ? Because there is several ways, how concatenated, all, prefix, suffix ?

Answer (score 1):

first, you can generate a list from numbers, and then you can convert the type of the elements to a string.

```
mylist=list(range(3000,3101))
convertlist = list()
for x in mylist:
    convertlist.append(str(x))
   
print(convertlist)
print(type(convertlist[0]))
```